# Product grid not posting values M2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, product-grid, post-data

I am using this extension https://github.com/webspeaks/productsgrid_magento2/tree/master/Webspeaks/ProductsGrid for my custom module where am attaching the product to the series. But when I post data of Main tab & Select Product tab, I am getting only product tab data. If I don't select products then I get main tab data.

Does anyone face the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I figured out why values was not posting because in my custom table field was name and product table also has name field they were conflicting with each other. I changed the name to series_name now everything as it should :)